# a composition of reflections

Tags: geometry, problem-solving

I got a question:

> Let $F\colon\mathbb{E}^3 \to \mathbb{E}^3;\; (x, y, z) \mapsto (−y, x, z + 1)$ be an isometry. Then we can consider $F$ as a composition of $n$ reflections. What is the minimum value of $n$? Also define these reflections explicitly.

So I tried to find reflections so it would work but I don't understand it at all. I looked here for more information and there was a similar question but he already found that it can be written by a composition of $4$ reflections.

Is there someone who can help me trough the question with hints so that I can understand it?

Comment: What course or text is this from?

Comment: the course is geometry